# Como chamar outra Activity/tela com Java no Totalcross?

Tags: java, totalcross

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com java através de uma ferramenta chamada Totalcross e preciso chamar uma outra tela/actividy mas não sei qual o código para fazer isso.

Em android seria o equivalente a isto:

```
public void ChamaRelatorios(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Relatorios.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Já tentou dar uma olhada na [documentação](https://totalcross.com/en/)?

Answer (score 1):

Para chamar uma tela no Totalcross é bem simples. Se você estiver na MainWindow e deseja chamar uma classe que herde de container você usa esse comando:

```
 public void initUI() {
         this.swap(new NomeClasse());
 }
```

Mas se você já estiver em uma classe que herde de container e quiser chamar outra, você usa esse comando aqui:

```
 MainWindow.getMainWindow().swap(new NomeClasse());
```